# Under what conditions will the ring homomorphism $\phi : R \to S$ satisfy the following results about prime and maximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ and $S$ be rings and $\phi : R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism.

*Here, I am considering that $R$ and $S$ don't necessarily have multiplicative identities.*

***MOTIVATION :***

I know that the pre-image of a prime ideal is prime if $R$ and $S$ are commutative. **But is this a necessary condition ?**
Similarly, I know that the pre-image of a maximal ideal need not be maximal even if $R$ and $S$ are commutative.
**But then, what are the sufficient conditions for this to hold ? And what are the sufficient conditions ?**

***QUESTION :***

Basically, I am interested in knowing the **necessary conditions** and the **sufficient conditions** for the following to hold:

1. **Image of a prime ideal is prime.**
2. **Pre-image of a prime ideal is prime.**
3. **Image of a maximal ideal is maximal.**
4. **Pre-image of a maximal ideal is maximal.**

*These conditions can be on the rings (e.g. commutativity, having unity, etc.) or on the homomorphism itself (e.g. injectivity, surjectivity, etc.)*

***P.S.***

I know that this is a lot to ask! And some arguments might be trivial to see. But my aim to compare these situations with each other to get a better understanding of what's going on. Also, this might serve as **a one-stop solution** for anyone interested in any of these problems and trying to get some help from this website.

*Any help/input shall be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: You are asking twice for sufficient conditions for the pre-image of a maximal ideal to be maximal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell provide an answer for the case of commutative rings having unity.

**Proposition 1:** Image of a prime(respectively maximal) ideal containing the ideal $I:=\ker \phi$ of $R$ is prime(respectively maximal) in the subring $R':= Im \phi$ of $S$(show that is it indeed a subring!).(I'm not sure if this is true in the general case but I suspect not).

**Proposition 2**: The pre-image of a prime ideal is prime. This is NOT true in general for maximal ideals (see counterexample below).

**Proposition 3:** The pre-image of maximal ideal under a **surjective** ring homomorphism is maximal.

**Proof of Proposition 1**: Let $M$ be a prime(respectively maximal) ideal of $R$ containing $I$ and let , so that $\phi:R \twoheadrightarrow R'$ is surjective. Let $M':=\phi(M)$ be an ideal in $R'$(show that it is indeed an ideal!).
We have the following chain of maps $$R \xrightarrow{\phi} R' \xrightarrow{\psi} R'/M'$$ where $\psi:R' \twoheadrightarrow R'/M'$ is the natural ring homomorphism(surjective as well).
$\ker(\phi)=I, \ker(\psi)=M'=\phi(M) \implies \ker(\psi \circ \phi)= M \cup I=M$

So the First Isomorphism theorem on the composition map gives $R/M \cong R'/M'$

So, $I \subseteq M \subseteq R$ is prime(respectively maximal) implies $R/M \cong R'/M'$ is an integral domain(repectively field) implies $M'=\phi(M)$ is prime(respectively maximal) in $R'=Im(\phi)$.

**Proof of Proposition 2:** Let $P \subseteq S$ be a prime ideal. It is easy to show that $\phi^{-1}(P)$ is an ideal. Let $a,b \in R$ such t hat $ab \in \phi^{-1}(P) \implies \phi(a)\phi(b) \in P \implies \phi(a) \in P$ or $\phi(b) \in P \implies
a \in \phi^{-1}(P)$ or $b \in \phi^{-1}(P)$. Hence $\phi^{-1}(P)$ is prime.

*Counter-example for maximal ideals:* $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be the natural inclusion ring homomorphism. The Zero Ideal $I=(0)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$(since it is a field), but $\phi^{-1}((0))=(0)$ is clearly not a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof of Proposition 3:** This follows directly from the converse of Proposition 1(this holds too!, just reverse all steps in the proof) Try to show this yourself.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot !  This will help.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am also interested in knowing whether all these 3 propositions will FAIL if we remove the commutativity condition for both rings ? Or may be just one ring ? And do we really need the unity in both these rings ?

Comment: @Another_Ramanujan_Fan Sorry I haven't studied non commutative rings or rings without unity. Even if some property doesn't apparently make use of these facts, it may be subtly present in the background.

Comment: Yeah! I get it. Thanks once again for such a great answer.